# awk different behaviour in command line and in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have this script which works fine

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "USAGE: `basename $0` username"
  exit 1
fi

logins=`last | grep $1`
times=`echo "$logins" | awk '{print $10}'`
timesCleared=`echo "$times" | sed -e 's/(//' -e 's/)//'`
minutes=`echo "$timesCleared" | awk -F: '{ print $1*60+$2}'`
total=0
for m in $minutes
do
  total=$(( $total + $m ))
done

echo $total > out.txt
cat out.txt
```

but, for an example, when i try this command in the interactive shell it doesn't work (    echo $minutes gives a different output):

```
echo "in 02:16 00:28 00:16 00:25 02:44 00:09" | awk -F: '{ print $1*60+$2;}'
```

it prints 16

if i write echo $minutes in the scripts it gives me the right output:

```
0 136 28 16 25 164 9
```

Does anyone know why is this?

Comment: Looks like there oughta be some escaping....  If it's not with the dollar signs, then it's with the math operators, + - * /.

Comment: `in` does not make sense as a number, so is evaluated as zero. (Yes, there is a numeric suffix, but this is what's going on here.)

Comment: Also, some of the lines I'm getting contain strings like `3+23:27`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables in your script contain newlines, which are important. What is being sent to `awk` in the line which assigns to the variable `minutes` is not

```
in 02:16 00:28 00:16 00:25 02:44 00:09
```

as in your command-line, but rather

```
in
02:16
00:28
00:16
00:25
02:44
00:09
```

In the first case, awk sees `$1` as `in 02` and `$2` as `16 00`. In the second case, it works on each line individually. When awk converts a string to a number, it uses only the first characters of the string; if it does not find a number at the beginning (as with the string `in 02`), it converts it to 0 without any error message.

You can use the `RS` awk pseudo-variable to set the record separator to a space:

```
echo "in 02:16 00:28 00:16 00:25 02:44 00:09" |
    awk -F: -v RS=' ' '{ print $1*60+$2;}'
```

Alternatively, you could echo the string with newlines:

```
echo "in
02:16
00:28
00:16
00:25
02:44
00:09" | awk -F: '{ print $1*60+$2;}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The string you `echo` in the script is newline-separated, not space-separated; so the command you tried interactively is not doing the same thing.

To reproduce what's going on in the script, try

```
echo "in 02:16 00:28 00:16 00:25 02:44 00:09" |
tr ' ' '\n' |
awk -F: '{ print $1*60+$2;}'
```

Comment: Yes, i suspected it might be the formatting. This works :)